# Iterating on HTTP API data from source

Tags: java, python, api, http

I am reading data from HTTP API using python urllib as follows:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
stations = json.loads(response.read().decode())
for station in stations:
    producer.send("test", json.dumps(station).encode())
```

Something I notice is that data is first converted to Bytes type when applying read function. Then, it's stored in a list (stations) which I'll be iterating on.

Since I'm dealing with very large HTTP responses, I would need to iterate over data directly from the HTTP API without storing it intermediately in my disk or RAM. Would it be possible to deal with this need in Python?

I would also want to know if this Java sample code can resolve my issue :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL(url);
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            producer.send("test", inputLine)
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Python [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library has support for [Streaming Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests). This allows you to read the response per line, without taking the entire response in memory.